# How to append multiple dataframes with same prefix in python

Tags: python, pandas, append

I have multiple sequential dataframe like this:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame( [['tom', 10], ['nick', 15], ['juli', 14]] ,  columns = ['Name', 'Age'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([['tom', 10], ['nick', 15], ['juli', 14]] ,  columns = ['Name', 'Age'])
df3 = pd.DataFrame([['tom', 10], ['nick', 15], ['juli', 14]] ,  columns = ['Name', 'Age'])
df4 = pd.DataFrame([['tom', 10], ['nick', 15], ['juli', 14]] ,  columns = ['Name', 'Age'])
```

I need to create a for loop to append them and get a new dataframe. 
I tried the codes below, but it doesnt work, as python recognise df1 as a string.

```
tempdf = df1
for i in range(2,4):
     tempdf = tempdf.append(("df"+str(i)))
     print(tempdf)
```

How do I get python to recognise them as dataframe objects I created?

Comment: if I were you, I will create a list that contains all that dataframes. i.e `df = [df1, df2, df3, df4]`. You mentioned you have 20 dataframes, which I find a bit hard to believe that they are all hand-coded. If the dataframes come from an iterable, I suggest storing that result in iterable as well ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were proceeding in correct direction, just use `eval`:

```
tempdf = df1
for i in range(2,4):
     tempdf = tempdf.append(eval("df"+str(i)))
     print(tempdf)
```

Note: Using eval can run arbitrary code, using it is considered a bad practice. Please try to use other ways, if possible.

Comment: It's a bad practice, agreed, but in OP's case it seems to be an easiest alternate solution.

Answer (score 2):

First, I should highlight that having to do this suggests a problem in the way the source dataframes were generated, and you should look into fixing that.

With Python, there are ways to do almost anything you want. Whether it is *desirable* to make use of such power is another question altogether.

In this case, the safest way would probably be to use `globals()`:

```
n_dataframes = 4
g = globals()
dataframes = [g[f'df{i}'] for i in range(1, n_dataframes + 1)]

result_df = pd.concat(dataframes)    
print(result_df)
```

Output:

```
   Name  Age
0   tom   10
1  nick   15
2  juli   14
0   tom   10
1  nick   15
2  juli   14
0   tom   10
1  nick   15
2  juli   14
0   tom   10
1  nick   15
2  juli   14
```

You can perform further processing on the result, such as calling `reset_index`.

Another alternative is to use `eval`, which veers firmly into "you shouldn't do this unless you really know what you're doing" territory, because it allows execution of arbitrary code:

```
dataframes = [eval(f'df{i}') for i in range(1, n_dataframes + 1)]
```

Note that the above code uses *f-strings*, which are syntax introduced only in Python 3.6. Accordingly, if your Python version is below that, replace `f'df{i}'` with `'df{}'.format(i)`.

Comment: BTW, it would be nice to mention that _f-string_ is only supported in python 3.6 and above.